# How do I prepend a zero to a digit with sed?

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to add a zero to the middle of a line of formatted text using sed or awk.

#### Example Input File

```
line 1

line 2

line 3
```

#### Expected Output

```
line 01

line 02

line 03
```

Comment: If we had slightly more information, we could provide more help. For instance, does the "line" text have spaces or tabs in it? Is that a space between "line" and "1", or is that a tab?

Answer (score 2):

There is some ambiguity with your question but how about using `printf` with `awk` to pad the second field with zeros:

```
$ awk 'NF==2 { printf "%s %02d\n", $1, $2}' file
line 01
line 02
line 03
line 10
line 100

$ awk 'NF==2 { printf "%s %04d\n", $1, $2}' file
line 0001
line 0002
line 0003
line 0010
line 0100
```

If you don't want blank lines stripped do `awk 'NF==2 { printf "%s %04d\n", $1, $2} NF!=2' file`.

Comment: +1 for a good solution but the above would strip the blank lines.

Comment: @EdMorton I was editing as you posted `:]` would be nice to have a representative example because I'm sure that actual file will have more than 2 fields anyway.

Comment: Agreed. I'd probably not use the same condition negated but use `next` instead: `awk 'NF==2 { printf "%s %04d\n", $1, $2; next} 1`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use a POSIX Character Class with Backreference

Given */tmp/foo* containing:

```
line 1

line 2

line 3
```

you can call `sed 's/[[:digit:]]/0&/' /tmp/foo` in order to get the following output:

```
line 01

line 02

line 03
```

Comment: Note this will only work for single digits, `line 10` becomes `line 0100` to fix this use  `sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+/0&/'`

Answer (score 0):

In awk this is quite easy:

```
awk '{print $1, 0$2}' input.txt > output.txt
```

In this case the input text you have shown is in the file `input.txt` and I saved it to a new file `output.txt`.

This is also an easy command to understand. The `$1` variable is your "line" text and the `$2` variable is your number. This command assumes there are no spaces in your "line" text. Are there?

Comment: Just be aware that would do more than simply put a zero in front of the 2nd field. If the OPs input file is tab-separated, for example, then it won't be any longer after that operation. You could also just use `,` instead of `" "` if you want to use this approach since that's what the OFS is designed for.

Comment: @EdMorton Agreed. If I knew a little bit more about what was in that "line" text, I could make this more robust, to be sure. But all I can do right now is assume the OP wrote exactly what he wanted.

Comment: That's fine but it's just worth saying since the OP probably wouldn't be able to guess there were consequences.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to your question as posted is:

```
sed 's/ / 0/'
```

If that doesn't do it, post some more representative input and expected output as there are many things you might need to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\</0/2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF==2{$2="0"$2}1' your_file
```